# How to inverse VLOOKUP for data entry?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My table has a date column to to the left (Column A). Other columns have share quantities and values.  Using standard VLOOKUP, I can retrieve values for a given date.

However: I have new transactions, which regularly need to be added to the master table. What I need is an "inverse" function, that allows me to append (or even over-write) data to the underlying table.

So far, my searches for an "inverse" function only give me alternate ways to retrieve (with the columns out of order). Any suggestions for an appropriate method?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is a script that can add data to the end of a table, or change data on an existing cell.  Functions only work by reading data in other parts of the spreadsheet and outputting the result in the cell that they were written in.  I don't think you're going to find a formula that sends data to another part of the spreadsheet.

If a script is what you're after let me know.  I use scripts like that so I can code a few code snippets.

Comment: I've been avoiding scripts and macros. The security implications associated with these can cause troubles. Still, it may be the best workable solution (sigh).

Answer (score 0):

Please check INDEX MATCH functions.

Comment: Checked. Great way to retrieve data from a large table. Still fails to meet my need to append / modify the data in that table.